# PrettyPhoto Error: Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and the image exists

Tags: youtube, href, prettyphoto

I've searched a series of forums and I've noticed that a lot of people had this same issue. I tried all the resolutions: using the longer Youtube URL like

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkqS5DiF2_A

defining the width and height of the image, and I've tried using older versions of JQuery. I'm still receiving the error. I've linked all the images in the CSS file [incorrectly, but they are linked :)]. I've been trying to solve this for days and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think I'm getting closer. I believe something isn't being linked properly. It's not in the CSS file, I'm looking in the JQuery files but am not absolutely sure what I'm looking for. Has anyone come across this issue with PrettyPhoto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links to the youtube video are not direct, you are using some kind of redirects. i suggest you use direct links to the youtube video

here is a demo of your site http://www.mediafire.com/?vj3l062uza7ov61 , see the left video

Comment: Thanks! Definitely a big help!

Answer (score 8):

It appears that you have to add `?iframe=true` to the end of the hyperlink

https://stackoverflow.com/===>http://stackoverflow.com?iframe=true
did the trick for me. Make sure you point direct to the web page you want to appear in the light box, not to the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue with WordPress,
I simply removed the alert.

file: /wp-content/plugins/prettyphoto-media/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.min.js

I use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to unfold the code
and comment line 350:

```
//alert("Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist.");
```